# Teenage book about a girl falling in love with a bad-boy ghost

Tags: story-identification, novel, ghost

I have a sneaking suspicion this is a *[Fear Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_Street)* book, but I'm having no luck pinning it down from the lists online. The protagonist is a teenage girl, who starts seeing a ghost in her bedroom. Nothing terribly saucy happens, but she gets to talking to him, and eventually starts being interested in him romantically. I want to say he's dressed like a stereotypical [greaser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greaser_(subculture)), although that might be influenced by the book art, which I remember as showing the two of them in her bedroom with him being slightly transparent. He can't remember who he is, or how he died. I don't remember if there were any visible wounds on his spirit body that might have clued her in. Eventually, through some set of circumstances, she runs into him outside of her bedroom, except he's alive, and doesn't recognize her, leading to a climax where she realizes that somehow his ghost traveled back in time, and he hasn't died yet. He gets into a fight, and a knife gets drawn. I don't remember if she manages to intervene before he gets stabbed, and whether he survives.

I believe I read this somewhere in Kentucky in the mid 1990s in a paperback book, maybe 150ish pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it with a search for `"rl stine" girl falls in love with ghost`. [*Haunted*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176339.Haunted) is indeed #7 in the *Fear Street* books.

[image: Front cover of Haunted with the ghost appearing in jean jacket and white shirt]

> Melissa woke up screaming. The prowler was at her window…or was he? The recent headlines about a Fear Street prowler had everyone on edge. Her father now kept a loaded pistol in his bedroom. That made it even more frightening—and real.
>
> Then the haunting began: her new car driving as if someone else had taken control; her birthday presents ripped open by unseen hands; an invisible force trying to push her out the bedroom window.
>
> Out of the shadows of her bedroom came a menacing figure. Who was he? Did he really come from beyond the grave? And why had he come to kill her? If Melissa doesn’t solve the mystery fast, these questions will haunt her—to death!

I misremembered parts of the plot. The ghost does not know who he is, but he is certain that Melissa killed him, and actively attacks her until she convinces him to help solve his death.